# In extjs how to make validate json

Tags: json, extjs4

i am working in extjs+yii. I am having view as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView',
{
        extend:'Ext.view.View',
        id:'qbqnsViewId',
        alias:'widget.QbqnsView',
        store:'qb.QbqnsStore',
        autoScroll: true,
        config:
        {
            tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                '<div id="main">'+
                '</br>'+
            //  '<b>Question :-</b> {pollQuestion}</br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">Question :-</h1> {question} </br>'+

                '<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property within the data
                 '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{optionId}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                //'<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{questionId}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                '</tpl></p>'+
                '<p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</tpl>',
            itemSelector:'div.main' 
        }
});// End of login class
```

This view is displaying Questions and its related options.Now after selecting answers and click of submit button i want to send Questionid and its selected radio button option. As data goes in format of json,i am capturing these selected radio buttons value, making jsons and after that passing it as parameter. So in controller i have written code as-

```
var answers = '{"data":[';
        var i=0;
        QbqnsStore.each(function(model){
            i++;
            var inputs = document.getElementsByName(model.get('questionId'));
            console.log(document.getElementsByName(model.get('questionId')));
            console.log("length is"+inputs.length);
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                if (inputs[j].checked) {
                    console.log("count of store is"+QbqnsStore.count());
                    //if (i == QbqnsStore.count()){
                    if (i == QbqnsStore.count()){
                        console.log("value of i is"+i);
                        answers = answers + '{"paperId":"'+paperNumber+'","userId":"'+userId+'","questionId":"'+inputs[j].name+'","option":'+inputs[j].value+'}'
                    //i=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("value of i is"+i);
                        answers = answers + '{"paperId":"'+paperNumber+'","userId":"'+userId+'","questionId":"'+inputs[j].name+'","option":'+inputs[j].value+'},'
                    }
                }
            }// End of inner for loop
        }); //End of each

        answers =answers+']}';
        console.log("selected data is:");
        console.log(answers);
        var storeObject=this.getStore('qb.QbquestionoptionStore');
        storeObject.load({

            params:{
                data: answers 
            },
            callback: function(records,operation,success){

            },
            scope:this
        });
```

Its working correctly when user solves all Questions. In case of solvage of all Questions,above function is forming json as-

```
{"data":[{"paperId":"1517","userId":"116","questionId":"1","option":1},{"paperId":"1517","userId":"116","questionId":"2","option":4},{"paperId":"1517","userId":"116","questionId":"3","option":9},{"paperId":"1517","userId":"116","questionId":"4","option":9}]}
```

Its in correct format. But when user is solving only first one or two Questions from paper,then its forming json as-

```
{"data":[{"paperId":"1518","userId":"116","questionId":"2","option":4},]}
```

i.e. extra comma get inserted at end of json which makes it invalidate json. So how to remove this extra comma from json when user solves only starting one or two Questions. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition is never true. Have you tried :

```
if (i == QbqnsStore.count() - 1){
```

instead of

```
if (i == QbqnsStore.count()){
```

?